# стандартный модуль auth в lavarel 5.4 откуда имя таблицы

Tags: laravel, auth

Подскажите, используя стандартный модуль auth в lavarel 5.4 хочу создать нового юзера
Страница Login открывается и сабмититься(без успешного логина, так как юзера нет ). Страница Register при сабмите выдает ошибку

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "pd_users" does not exist
LINE 1: select count(*) as aggregate from "pd_users" where "email" =...
^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "pd_users" where "email" = 
wprods@site.com)
```

В модели :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'ion_users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

In config/database.php для pgsql прописан

```
    'prefix' => 'pd_',
```

Непонятно, откуда берет имя таблицы для регистрации как не из модуля выше и при логине ошибку не выдает ?

Answer (score -1):

```
php artisan migrate
```

надо запустить миграции судя по всему